# Intermediate Value Theorem: Prove that there is $x$ such that $f(x+1)-f(x)=\frac{f(2)-f(1)}{2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

We have continuous function $f:[0,2]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Prove that there are $x_1,x_2$ such that $x_2-x_1=1$ and $f(x_2)-f(x_1)=\frac{f(2)-f(1)}{2}$

I was thinking about it a lot and can't find solution so I would be thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: Could it be that you meant $f(x+1)-f(x)=\frac{f(2)-f(0)}{2}$ ?

Comment: I think Martin R must be right.  Otherwise, $f(x) = 4x-x^2$ seems like a counterexample.

Comment: OP: The title and the main body are switched around.  In the title, we have $f(x+1)-f(x)$, but in the body, we have $f(x_1)-f(x_1+1)$.

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk It doesn't make sense to me. For the identity function $f(x)=x$, $f(x+1)-f(x)$ will always be $1$, not $1/2$...

Comment: After revision current form is correct, as far as original content goes. I don't know what authors meant but it's cleary written $x_2-x_1=1$ and $f(x_2)-f(x_1)=\frac{f(2)-f(1)}{2}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is written in the assumption that you actually
meant $\frac {f(2) - f(0)}2$ instead of $\frac {f(2) - f(1)}2$.
Otherwise the statement would be wrong, as the example
$f(x) = 4x - x^2$ [given by Brian Tung](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592869/intermediate-value-theorem-prove-that-there-is-x-such-that-fx1-fx-frac/1592905#comment3243766_1592869) demonstrates:
$\frac {f(2) - f(1)}2 = \frac 12$, but $f(x+1)-f(x) = 3-2x \ge 1$
for  $0 \le x \le 1$.

---

Consider the function $g: [0, 1] \to \Bbb R$,  $g(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)$.

From the intermediate value theorem it follows that $g$ takes on
every value between $g(0) = f(1) - f(0)$ and $g(1) = f(2) - f(1)$.

In particular, there is a $x$ such that
$$
 g(x) = \frac {g(0) + g(1)}2 = \frac {f(2) - f(0)}2 \, .
$$